# Free or paid for quality bible data available for download?

Tags: licensing, json

Where do the "bible apps" for iPhone and such get their data? Are they purchasing it from somewhere? Where can I find quality bible data for download, free or paid (ideally not *too* expensive)?

The bible data should include things like the full text as JSON/XML/etc., be usable in commercial products somehow (through licensing or open source), and/or extra metadata related to the texts such as mapping of words to definitions or mapping to translations in different languages, counting words, etc.. Could also have bibles in multiple languages.

Where do you get the highest quality of this data for use in commercial products? I found [this](https://hackathon.bible/data/) list of links, but not sure if that is a good place to continue my search. For example, one link says:

> ABS BibleSearch API @ API.Bible – American Bible Society (free)
> With nearly 2500 Bible versions available across over 1600 languages, API.Bible offers the largest collection of Bibles available. The Bible Search Application Programming Interface (API) allows any developer to include Scripture content and text anywhere in their website or application for non-commercial purposes. Access via XML or JSON requests served over HTTP using RESTful resources.

That is useless, because it can't be used for commercial purposes :/

Answer (score 1):

Wikisource has many bible versions, in many languages, as wikitext.

It does not contain any mappings, words count or much metadata, unfortunately.

Example page: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bible_(King_James)/Genesis

Wikisource has [20 different bibles in English](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bible), and more in [40 other languages](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bible). Many of them do not have the full data, though.